# Communicating derived C++ types through a named pipe impossible?

Tags: c++, ipc

I found that communicating a derived C++ type such as an opencv Mat or other derived types do go through the pipe if I send the derived type as a reference through a pipe:

> ```
>    //Measurement FIFO
>     while(1)
>     {
>     Mat xboxobs = some value;                //changes in every iteration
>     const char * obsfifo = "/tmp/obsfifo";
>     mkfifo(obsfifo, 0666);                       
>     fm = open(obsfifo, O_WRONLY | O_NONBLOCK);         
>     write(fm, &xboxobs, 1024 ); 
>     close(fm); 
>     }
> ```
>
> and read the reference in the reader as follows::

```
    while(1)
    {
     //READ kalman measurement fifo
    const char * obsfifo = "/tmp/obsfifo";
    fm = open(obsfifo, O_RDONLY );
    Mat xboxobs;
    read(fm, &obs, 1024 );
    close(fm);
    fflush(stdout);
    }
    unlink(obsfifo);
```

When I try to access the contents of `Mat xboxobs` in the reader by printing to `STDOUT` with `std::cout` or `printf`, I get errors. I am implementing the reader and writer on the same Linux machine.

**Question 1**: Is it generally impossible to move derived types safely through a named pipe or am I missing something here?

**Question 2**: As a bypass, I send each element of matrix `Mat xboxobs` and other `Mats` as floats through named pipes and I am having to communicate about 30 floats through individual pipes in `/tmp/somefifo`. Altogether I am sending 30 floats, 15 each from two separate C++ codes that run simultaneously, and I am aggregating the floats back into matrices in the receiver code.

The good thing is that this works but I have an extremely slow reading time (about 2 ~ 3 secs) between reading from each fifo, and assembling the matrix float elements back into matrices before using the matrices for other mathematical operations.

I also found that when I use do not use O_NONBLOCK in my writer code, when I implement the reader, the program freezes. Debugging with `gdb` tells me  nothing in particular but when I halt the debugging process, I get the following:

> 0x00007ffff68ba870 in __write_nocancel ()
>       at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
>   81  ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S: No such file or directory.

I am at a loss why I cannot seem to run the three programs safely without unblocking the writer code. And why is the receiver code so slow when I split the matrices up before sending? IS this normal?

I would surely appreciate any help.

Comment: You cannot communicate pointers between the processes at each end of the pipe, but you can/have to communicate the data through the pipe. So it's correct to send the floats. But that should actually take not much time, and surely not 2~3 seconds. The most expensive call is opening the fifo on both sides. It might be better to use local network sockets if you work with multiple senders.

Comment: @ikrabbe: One addition not worth an answer. A crazy programmer **can** communicate pointers, albeit not with pipes. Use shared memory or a memory-mapped file and map it exactly to the same location of the processes’ memory address space. Then make a custom memory allocator (operating in said memory map) and constructors–destructors relying on it. If all data to be transferred don’t contain pointers outside that common memory region, then transfer of pointers is possible.

Comment: Thanks! Can you give me a minimal working example?

Comment: According to your question, your writer code declares `xboxobs` and writes from `&xboxobs`, whereas your reader code declares `xboxobs` and reads into `&obs`.

Answer (score 4):

`read` and `write` don't take a reference; they take a *pointer*. Prefix-& is the address-of operator, which returns a pointer. It's *postfix*-& which indicates a reference.

Passing data to another program in this manner *can* work, but *only* under the following circumstances:

1. The class does not use pointers, but stores everything inside the class itself
2. The c++ ABI used for both programs is the same (which is defined by compiler and c++ standard library)
3. The definition of your class (and any other classes that it uses) is the same in both programs
4. The compiler is invoked at the same optimization level for both programs

If even one of these is not the case, chances are pretty high that the offsets of some of the data elements in your class will be different, and then things will go *boom*. If you're lucky, it will even do this *every* time, rather than seemingly at random.

A better way to pass data to another program is to use a serialisation library. There are several to choose from; a popular one is [included with boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html)

Comment: Do you have a good website that describes boost serialization with named pipes in mind?

Comment: not really, but then serialization is just transformation of your data to an implementation-independent format; what happens after that (send it through named pipe, over the network, or to a file for later reference) is unimportant to it; so you should be able to use just any tutorial on boost serialization, and just any tutorial on named pipes, and combine the two.